# programmatically removing html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation with my web api web application. When started the application shows empty map, when I press search another map appears. My question is how to programmatically remove first map. These are the pictures that explain the situation(on start):

[image]

When search is clicked:
[image]

This is my html code for map:

```
<div id="world-map" class="forDelete" style="width: 600px; height: 400px" >

    </div>
```

An this is what i tried. I added next line of code to the function that draws map when search is clicked.

```
$("#forDelete").Remove();
```

Any suggestions why this doesn't work? Or possible solution? 
p.s. I code in html and java script for the first time.

Comment: `$("#forDelete").Remove();` has to be `$(".forDelete").remove();`

Comment: if you are using jquery then `$(".forDelete").remove();`

Comment: @Roberrrt still the same, it dosen't get deleted

Comment: @gurvinder372   still the same, it dosen't get deleted

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: My bad, code you gave worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a class so it's not with a hash. It should be then like this:

```
$(".forDelete").remove();
```

Otherwise if you want to use the idi of your element:

```
$("#world-map").remove();
```

Also remember JS is caps sensitive so it is not .Remove but **.remove()**

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function (if ***Remove*** is a function).

Please use **.remove()**.

You can see more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Edit:

As other answer says, you are also, using the wrong ***selector***, for classes you must use ***"."*** See [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can use both remove() and detach() method

```
jQuery("#world-map").remove(); or jQuery("#world-map").detach();
```

Using normal javascript

```
var elem = document.getElementById('world-map');
 elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```